# Language and Algorithm to Take Derivatives in Function Notation

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, partial-derivative, programming

I want to algorithmically find derivatives and partial derivatives of expressions written in function notation.  For example, I can type "d/dx f(x, y(x), g(x) * h(x))" directly into Wolfram Alpha, without defining any of the referenced functions more specifically.  I'd like to work with code which is able to do this.

Unfortunately, I don't own Mathematica, but I do have basic MATLAB and anything for Windows that's free (Python, R, etc.).  If the code is significantly easier to work with in Mathematica than anywhere else, I might get it, but free alternatives would be preferred.

How can I perform these sorts of calculations in code?

Comment: Have you tried the [wolfram cloud](https://www.wolframcloud.com/browse)?